# Verification code always invalid Swift Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

Im using SMS verification to verify users. My problem is that when I enter a code to verify I get invalid code. I can't for the life of me figure out why.

Calling cloud code function:

```
@IBAction func verifyCodeButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    var verificationCode: String = verificationCodeTextField.text!
    let textFieldText = verificationCodeTextField.text ?? ""

    if verificationCode.utf16.count < 4 || verificationCode.utf16.count > 4 {
        displayAlert("Error", message: "You must entert the 4 digit verification code sent yo your phone")
    } else {
        let params = ["verificationCode" : textFieldText]
        PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("verifyPhoneNumber", withParameters: params, block: { (object: AnyObject?, error) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showVerifyCodeView", sender: self)
            } else {
                self.displayAlert("Sorry", message: "We couldnt verify you. Please check that you enterd the correct 4 digit code sent to your phone")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Cloud code to verify code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("verifyPhoneNumber", function(request, response) {
    var user = Parse.User.current();
    var verificationCode = user.get("phoneVerificationCode");
    if (verificationCode == request.params.phoneVerificationCode) {
        user.set("phoneNumber", request.params.phoneNumber);
        user.save();
        response.success("Success");
    } else {
        response.error("Invalid verification code.");
    }
});
```

Comment: Why would you need to use .utf16? Also `x < 4 || x > 4` can be written as `x != 4`. Also, you're not showing us the verification code sending part.

Answer (score 1):

Your parameter names are mismatched between the iOS and JS code.

`verificationCode` vs `phoneVerificationCode`

Change

```
let params = ["verificationCode" : textFieldText]
```

To use the same parameter name:

```
let params = ["phoneVerificationCode" : textFieldText]
```

**EDIT**

Other issues I see with the code:

The first two lines of the iOS code create a variable and a constant from the textField's text value. Get rid of the `verificationCode` variable and just use the `textFieldText` constant.

I would add some more error states to the Cloud Code before you check if the codes are equivalent. First check if the parameter exists and the expected type and length:

```
var requestCode = request.params.phoneVerificationCode;
if ((typeof requestCode !== "string") || (requestCode.length !== 4)) {
  // The verification code did not come through from the client
}
```

Then perform the same checks on the value from the user object:

```
else if ((typeof verificationCode !== "string) || (verificationCode.length !== 4)) {
  // There is not a verification code on the Parse User
}
```

Then you can continue to checking if `requestCode` and `verificationCode` are equivalent.

Comment: I changed that but still getting invalid code! Good catch though!

Comment: @m1234 I have edited my answer to add more problems I see with the sample code in the original question.

Comment: Thanks Ive updated my code to your suggestions and I'm still getting invalid code